# How can I secure Branch.io install web hook?

Tags: web, branch.io

I need to secure the install web hook so I would know that the request is coming from Branch.io and not from something else.
The are saying it can be done like [this](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/webhooks/support/#how-can-i-ensure-a-webhook-is-from-branch)

But, where I can set that custom event (key, value) on the mobile side of the application?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting a parameter in the branch link and when the event reaches the server I check for the parameter value.
It's over https so I guess it's secure.

Answer (score 0):

Alex with Branch here: as you discovered, unfortunately it's not currently possible to add a (key, value) pair to Branch's default `install` event. Your method of appending a parameter to the incoming Branch link is a good solution, as long as you only need to catch users who have opened that Branch link prior to installing the app.

For an approach that covers *all* installs, including those not coming through a Branch link, you could use a custom event configured to fire on the same criteria as the `install` event:

1. Initialize a Branch session in your app.
2. In the callback parameters (full list [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/ios/#branch-provided-data-parameters-in-callback)), check for the value of `+is_first_session`.
3. If `+is_first_session` returns `true`, then this is the first time that device has been seen (a.k.a., the criteria for `install`) and you can [define a custom event](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/tracking-events/#custom-events) with the secret (key, value) pair of your choice.

For example, using Objective-C for iOS:

```
[[Branch getInstance] userCompletedAction:@"myCustomEvent" withState:@{@"branch_specific_identifier":@"123-AB-456"}];
```

Then when you configure your webhook on the Branch dashboard, you can take a couple of different approaches:

1. Pass all `myCustomEvent` events to your endpoint, and then [examine the postback](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/webhooks/advanced/#sample-return-for-all-other-events) to ensure `branch_specific_identifier` is set appropriately (this is similar to what you're probably already doing with the link parameter).
2. Use [webhook filters](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/webhooks/advanced/#filters) to prevent `myCustomEvent` events *without* appropriate `branch_specific_identifier` values from being sent to your server at all. To do this, you would use a (key, value) pair of `event.metadata.branch_specific_identifier : 123-AB-456` in the **Filter (Advanced)** box of the webhook configuration screen.

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw that filter in the Branch dashboard, it can be a solution. But, the downside is that if you want to change something you need to have backwards compatibility with older versions of the mobile app, not all users will update to the latest version. I needed something to be changed only on server. Appsflyer has a range of IPs that you can use as a security method.

Comment: @RobertGabriel that is a good point. I'll pass it along to our engineering team as something they can hopefully consider in future!